# Apply transformations to a number of data.frame objects

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to apply transformations to a number of data.frame objects. How would I do that? I was thinking I could loop somehow through those objects, but that was unfruitful so far. I think I might need to pass references to my data.frame objects to a list or some other kind of collection and then loop through those references. Is that even possible in R?

```
#reproducible data
foo=data.frame(c(1, 1), c(1, 1))
bar=data.frame(c(2, 2), c(2, 2))
#apply transformations
for (dat in list(foo, bar)){
    dat$NEW <- 9999
    print(dat)
}
#of course nothing happened since data.frames were copied to list object
print(foo) #no change
print(bar) #no change

#expected output
foo$NEW <- 9999
bar$NEW <- 9999
print(foo) #looks good 
print(bar) #looks good
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Maybe add an expected output?

Comment: I would like that the the return value of `print(foo)` and `print(bar)` are the same as that of `print(dat)` from the loop statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this and continue working with a list of data.frames

```
foo=data.frame(a = c(1, 1), b = c(1, 1))
bar=data.frame(a = c(2, 2), b = c(2, 2))

dat <- list(foo = foo, bar = bar)
dat <- lapply(dat, function(x){
  x$NEW = 999
  x
})
```

now dat looks as follows:

```
$foo
  a b NEW
1 1 1 999
2 1 1 999

$bar
  a b NEW
1 2 2 999
2 2 2 999
```

If you want to force `foo` to be the same as `dat$foo` you can use

```
mapply(assign, names(dat), dat, MoreArgs = list(envir = .GlobalEnv))
```

which results in

```
> foo
  a b NEW
1 1 1 999
2 1 1 999
```

and the same for `bar`

Comment: That's great! Still somewhat awkward compared to other languages. Btw, instead of the `mapply` it is possible to use `list2env(dat, globalenv())`